# Prove inequality holds on boundary

Tags: real-analysis

If $f(x) \le g(x)  $ for all $x \in $ U, where $f,g $ are continuous functions on  $\overline U$, how to prove that this inequality hold for all $x \in \overline U $ ?

Comment: Have you tried to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x \in \overline U$. Choose a sequence $x_n$ of elements in $U$ such that $x_n \to x$. This is possible because for all $\epsilon > 0$ we have $B_\epsilon(x) \cap U \neq \emptyset$ via the definition of $\overline U$. Then for all $n$:
$$ f(x_n) \leq g(x_n) $$
Apply the limit and the result follows.